# Unable to get image from public/images folder in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, multer

Process the image using `multer` and saved the path of image into MySQL database and the same image has been copied into `public/images/` folder too. Please see the attached screen shots.

In the React hooks `Home.js` screen while I am trying to get image as `src={photo}`, I am getting an error `Cannot GET /public/images/photo-1592130487996.PNG`

In the n/w tab the I am getting json response is showing like below, 
`...."privilege":"PLAYER","photo":"public\\images\\photo-1592130487996.PNG","position":"DEFENDER",....`

`server.js`

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/images/')));

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/images/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var ext = file.originalname.split('.').pop();
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + ext);
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

`Home.js`

```
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

            {
              searchResults.map(({ id, photo, position, phonenumber, name }) => (
                <div key={id} className="grid-item">
                  {
                    deleteIcon.show && (
                      <span className="deletePlayerButton" onClick={deletePlayer(id)}>
                        <img className="deletePlayerimg" src="/images/delete.png"></img>
                      </span>
                    )}
                  <div>
                    <img alt="" className="playerProfilePic_home_tile" key={photo} src={photo}></img>
                  </div>
                  <div className="playerProfile_grid_border">
                    <span className="rec_name_position_data">
                      <h3 key={name}>{name}</h3>
                      <span className="playerPosition_home_tile" key={position}>{position}</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <span className="phoneNumber_home">
                    <img src="/images/phone.png" alt={"phoneTooltip.show"} key={id} name="phoneNumberhomeicon" onClick={displayPhoneToolTip(id)} />
                  </span>
                  {phoneTooltip === id && (
                    <div className="tooltip_PhoneNumber_home" key={phonenumber}>{phonenumber}</div>
                  )}
                </div>
              ))
            }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try changing `path.join(__dirname, './public/images/')` to `path.join(__dirname, 'public')`

Comment: I have tried that earlier >> `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: But it doesn't work

Comment: Should i need to change in storage too ?

Comment: I have in storage too. `var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var ext = file.originalname.split('.').pop();
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + ext);
  }
})`

Comment: But still it is showing `Cannot GET /public/images/photo-1592130487996.PNG`

Comment: http://localhost:3000/public/images/photo-1592130487996.PNG, i can't see the image but it is loading the site, when i check in n/w tab and against the image it shows >>> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

Comment: Yes now i can see the image.

Comment: by giving this way as you sguggested http://localhost:3000/images/photo-1592130487996.PNG

Comment: that's because public word shouldn't be in the url and the path that should be saved in the database should be without public word

Comment: So may i know where should I correct that ?

Comment: The problem here is if i remove `public/images` and add just `images` in storage,, then the image are not copying into the images folder ? >>>  the `var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'images')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var ext = file.originalname.split('.').pop();
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + ext);
  }
})`

Comment: What's the permissions on the file? is it readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do following steps:

1. change

   ```
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/images/')));
   ```

   to

   ```
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
   ```

   because you want to serve static files from `public` folder, not `public/images` folder.
2. Remove the word `public` from the image path before you save the path in the database

   OR

   Remove the word `public` from the image path before you set it as a value to `src` attribute on the `img` element in the react app.

To remove the `public` word, you can either use [String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) or [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) functions.